# Dynamic query for Crystal Report, "No valid report source is available."

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports-2010

I am trying to create a Crystal Report with a dynamic data source.  When i click the report button, the crystal report shows up just fine, but when i click any button the Crystal Report tool bar (i.e. Next page, Export To, etc.), i get a pop with the Error "No valid report source is available."

Here is what my C# code looks like:

```
private void GenerateReport()
{
    using (DataContext reports = new DataContext())
    {
        var results = //Linq Query;

        ReportDocument pr = new ReportDocument();
        pr.Load(Server.MapPath(@"CrystalReport1.rpt"));
        pr.SetDataSource(results.ToList());

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = pr;
        CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I could not get this working with the other way, but i did get it to work going about it a different way.  First, i added a CrystalReportSource control to the aspx page,

```
<CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
   <Report FileName="CrystalReport1.rpt">
  </Report>
</CR:CrystalReportSource>
```

Then in the code behind file, instead of setting the datasource directly to CrystalReportViewer1, i set it to CrystalReportSource, then i set that as the report source for CrystalReportViewer1.  Now everything works just fine!

```
using (DataContext reports = new DataContext())
{
    var results = //Linq Query;
    CrystalReportSource1.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(results.AsEnumerable());

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSourceID = "CrystalReportSource1";
    CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just Solved this problem  using CrystalReportViewer **Navigate Event**

in View report Button  i have saved report document in a session

```
  Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   ' -- the ds is dataset variable containing data to be displayed in the report

    rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds)
    Session.Add("rptdoc", rptDoc)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc

    End Sub
```

then in Navigate event of CrystalReportViewer i set the CrystalReportViewer data source to the Session

```
Protected Sub j(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As CrystalDecisions.Web.NavigateEventArgs) Handles CrystalReportViewer1.Navigate

    rpt.SetDataSource(ds)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = session("rptdoc")

End Sub
```

So each time  before you  navigate to another page in the report , CrystalReportViewer data source is set to the report  document saved in the session.